# how to tell table draw heightForFooterInSection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My table view has 8 sections and I set the height for footer of the last section (section 7) is 80 so that the view of the table is friendly to user.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 7:
            return 80;
    }
    return 10;
}
```

My cell has a text field and i program so that when a keyboard pops up, I still can scroll the 
table and see every section. When the keyboard is dismissed, I notice that the height for footer of the last section has been shrinking a bit.

My question : how can I force me table to redraw the height for footer of sections after dismissing the keyboard

Answer (score -2):

you can call reloadData, methode of UITableView